# Using ngFor within <template> causes app to crash

Tags: angular, ngfor, plunker, transclusion

I'm working on a `angular2` app (version 2.4.1) and I'm trying to write a component that should take the template to be rendered from the user of the component (what was called transclusion in angular1 I believe).

I've written a component that uses [`ngTemplateOutlet`] to render a given template, however when passing it a template that uses ngFor it crashes because it tries to render the ngFor-content even though the array is null.

See the following plunker, which reproduces the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/E5Nj73ElOFGDRAdpBcGf?p=preview

The first ngFor renders correctly, but when the component test-template tries to render the template it is given it fails on:

> inline template:10:43 caused by: Cannot read property 'value' of
>   undefined

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated!

EDIT: The same code works with `Angular2 v2.1.2` https://plnkr.co/edit/0OyPqtvkDgTUPpwovZMc

Comment: I now have the same issue. I upgraded Angular from `2.1.2` to `2.4.1` and code much like your plunkr has stopped working with the same issue. I don't know if there is something with Angular2's "digest cycle" that has changed when using `ngTemplateOutlet`.

Comment: @Hampus Created a plunker with version `2.1.2` and it actually seems to work, so either we both are using it the wrong way or a bug has been introduced. Plunker with `2.1.2`: https://plnkr.co/edit/0OyPqtvkDgTUPpwovZMc